# How do I compile XAML and VB.NET into a wpf application WITHOUT visual studio

Tags: wpf, vb.net, compilation

I am someone who really hates not knowing why things happen. So what is really irking me right now is the fact that I can't figure out how to compile a WPF application WITHOUT VS.NET. I like using IDE's, but I usually prefer to do it the old fashioned way first. How do I take XAML and VB.NET code and compile it into a WPF application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build on the command line using [MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd393574(v=vs.100).aspx), as this is what Visual Studio does. It's also what you'd use if you were automating your builds as parts of a continuous integration framework.

You still need to have the files that make up the project organised in a project file - otherwise MSBuild won't know what to do, so it might be difficult to create a project from scratch this way. All of the project files are XML based so you can open them up in a text editor to see what files and settings are required.

You can build a pure VB project (no XAML) from the command line [as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/25fz1td5(v=vs.100).aspx)

[More information on the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970678(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much :) Sorry, it just drives me insane when i don't understand how things work

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a project file you can build it with [MSBuild](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx). [Ken Adeniji's Blog](https://kenadeniji.wordpress.com/) contains some basic application code if you really want to start from scratch, and [Microsoft's MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970678(v=vs.100).aspx) has more details on each step of the build process.